# Request for [parcheesi] to be a tag synonym of [pachisi]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We currently have the tag [pachisi](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pachisi). The tag wiki says:

> A pawn-moving board game that originated in ancient India. The westernized version is called "Parcheesi".

Earlier this month, we had a new question tagged with [parcheesi](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parcheesi). As the tag wiki above says, this is a westernized name of the same game.

Both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachisi) and [Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2136/pachisi) list the game as "Pachisi". Would it be possible to make [parcheesi](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parcheesi) and tag synonym of [pachisi](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pachisi)?

Comment: The answer on the one question about pachisi seems to indicate that the games are different, and that tag was only added to the question *after* the answer indicated that it should be. Are you sure they should be synonymized?

Comment: Board Game Geek lists "Parcheesi" as [an alternate name](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2136/pachisi/credits#alternatename) of "Pachisi", and forums posts, version listings, files, and others all use the two interchangeably. I couldn't find anything online about the difference between the two; just that "Parcheesi" is a trademarked term. I can't speak to the expertise of the answerer of the Pachisi question, but they seem interchangeable to me, much like how "Star Halma" and "Chinese Checkers" [are interchangeable](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/21384/3389).

Comment: In order to figure out if they are the same game, I've [asked a question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/32292/3389) on this site. We'll see what the top answers are.

Comment: Don't take my answer as a reason to not merge them.  I would merge the two tags.  I don't think the cultural difference between the the two versions is enough to warrant two tags.  As a Canadian with lots of recent games with lots of information available online I often find it hard to find all the details about these cultural games.

Answer (score 1):

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcheesi) Parcheesi is just a brand name version of Parchisi so it sounds like a good idea.

> Parcheesi is a brand-name American adaptation of the Indian cross and circle board game Pachisi, published by Parker Brothers[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcheesi) and Winning Moves. The game and its variants are known worldwide. A similar game called Parchís is popular in Spain and northern Morocco.[2] Parqués is its Colombian variant. A version is available in the United Kingdom under the name of Ludo.